# Attribute override has no impact

Tags: c#

```
public class SmsListFormModel
    {
        [MyRequired]
        [Display(Name = Translations.Global.MESSAGE)]
        public virtual string SmsMessage { get; set; }
    }
```

then I am doing override

```
public class SepaExportSmsListFormModel : SmsListFormModel
    {
        [Display(Name = Translations.Global.MESSAGE)]
        public override string SmsMessage { get; set; }
    }
```

so now SmsMessage should not me mandator any more.

But If I am checking code:

```
@Html.TextBoxAreaFor(x => x.SmsMessage)
```

and inside is code like:

```
var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
if (metaData.IsRequired) {....
```

but `SmsMessage` is always required even If I am overriding it. Why?
Attribute can not be overriden?

What is the solution?

Comment: What model type is your view using? And what overriding we are talking about here? These two model classes seem to be completely separated, and just happen to have the same field

Comment: sorry my mistake forget : SmsListFormModel

Comment: Assuming SepaExportSmsListFormModel inherits from SmsListFormModel, the Attribute class sets AttributeUsage Inherited property to true, see in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thank you, so you suggest using: [AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]

Comment: Yup, in your MyRequired implementation

Comment: thank you. so I will set Inherited = false and retest it

Comment: I tried but  var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData); still show me required is TRUE

Comment: ok I see why this doesn't work, the ModelMetadataProvider seems to use PropertyDescriptor for retrieving attributes, instead of plain Attribute.GetCustomAttributes. PropertyDescriptor.Attributes ignores happily the fact that attributeUsage.inherited is false. I guess there's no simple solution to that, how about just switching inheritance order? if SepaExportSmsListFormModel is the same as SmsListFormModel except SmsMessage is not required, how about inheriting SmsListFormModel from SepaExportSmsListFormModel? :) alternatively, you can always create two separate models with no inheritance

Comment: @Piotr with your help I found a solution:

Answer (score 0):

With @Piotr idea:

```
[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
```

I found a solution:

```
var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(Model => Model, ViewData);

var required = metaData.ContainerType.GetProperty(metaData.PropertyName).GetCustomAttributes(typeof (RequiredAttribute), false).Any();
```

Thank you